# Better way of placing multiple images pointing to another image in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have an image of the heatmap, in which each region represents a stage of the process. I want to show few images of process pointing towards heatmap. All these images are stacked vertically and the heatmap is placed next to the stack in vertically center style.

Below is the code snippet-

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzset{
  box/.style = {draw, rectangle, draw=white},
  to/.style  = {->, >=stealth', shorten >=1pt, thin, draw=orange, fill=orange}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (heatmap) at (0,0,0) {\includegraphics[width=60pt]{example-grid-100x100pt}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(heatmap.south east)},y={(heatmap.north west)}]
        \begin{scope}[x={(heatmap.south east)},y={(heatmap.north west)}]
            \draw (-.5,1.6) node[box] (one) {\includegraphics[width=40pt]{example-image-a}};
            \draw (-.5,0.8) node[box] (two) {\includegraphics[width=40pt]{example-image-b}};
            \draw (-.5,-.0) node[box] (three) {\includegraphics[width=40pt]{example-image-c}};
            \draw (-.5,-.8) node[box] (four) {\includegraphics[width=40pt]{example-image-c}};
                \draw[to] (one)   -- (0.99,0.50);
                \draw[to] (two)   -- (0.70,0.50);
                \draw[to] (three) -- (0.40,0.50);
                \draw[to] (four)  -- (0.10,0.50);
        \end{scope}
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The generated PDF looks like following-
[image: screenshot of the generated PDF]

**It is really difficult to place all these images in the proper place. Hence, I am looking for any better way to achieve the same.**

Comment: if "are stacked vertically" is just a fact an not a restriction, you could also use `positioning` library to distribute the figures around the heatmap.

Comment: Why two nested `scopes`? I think one is enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the `positioning` library of `TikZ`, see the `below = of` calls. See [PGF manual](http://ctan.mines-albi.fr/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) Section 17.5.3 p229 for more information.

The code below places the first image in the column `above left` of the heatmap, then all other images are successively placed below the previous one, at a `0.5cm` distance

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows,positioning}
\tikzset{
  box/.style = {draw, rectangle, draw=white},
  to/.style  = {->, >=stealth', shorten >=1pt, thin, draw=orange, fill=orange}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (heatmap) at (0,0,0) {\includegraphics[width=60pt]{example-grid-100x100pt}};
            \node[above left = 1cm of heatmap] (one) {\includegraphics[width=40pt]{example-image-a}};
            \node[below = 0.5cm of one] (two) {\includegraphics[width=40pt]{example-image-b}};
            \node[below = 0.5cm  of two] (three) {\includegraphics[width=40pt]{example-image-c}};
            \node[below = 0.5cm of three] (four) {\includegraphics[width=40pt]{example-image-c}};
            \draw[to] (one)   -- (0.99,0.50);
            \draw[to] (two)   -- (0.70,0.50);
            \draw[to] (three) -- (0.40,0.50);
            \draw[to] (four)  -- (0.10,0.50);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT** The snippet below shows how to connect one of the boxes to a specific cell in the grid. I added some length definitions to make it a bit easier. And I used the `calc` library of `TikZ` for this.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows,positioning,calc}
\tikzset{
  box/.style = {draw, rectangle, draw=white},
  to/.style  = {->, >=stealth', shorten >=0pt, thin, draw=orange, fill=orange}
}

\newlength{\gridwidth}
\setlength{\gridwidth}{60pt}
\newlength{\cellwidth}
\setlength{\cellwidth}{6pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0,outer sep=0pt] (heatmap) at (0,0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\gridwidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}};
            \node[above left = 1cm of heatmap] (one) {\includegraphics[width=40pt]{example-image-a}};
            \draw[to] (one)   -- ($(heatmap.south west)+ (1.5*\cellwidth,0.5*\cellwidth)$);            
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just one quick question, how do you position the arrow endpoint at a specific location in heatmap image?

Comment: @RaviJoshi, see the edit